# Is there a name for 'simple' two-input-one-output word problems?

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, primary-education, terminology, word-problems

- Andy has 4 apples, and then eats 2. How many does he have left?
- Beth drives for 3 hours at 80 km/h. How far did she go?
- Carl, Debbie and Earl earned $30 together shoveling driveways. How much does each of them get?

Is there a name for this sort of 'simplest possible' word problem?

Is there any well-defined classification or hierarchy of such problems?

For example, the third on my list requires the pre-processing step of recognizing group of **three** entrepreneurs before doing the division, which adds a degree of difficulty.

It seems to me that such a classification system might be pedagogically useful, but I don't know whether one exists or is widely accepted.

Comment: The third problem also hides the implicit assumption that they all earn the same amount, which really should be stated explicitly. (At least, I'm guessing that's supposed to be assumed, since otherwise there isn't a unique solution.)

Comment: See my comment [**here**](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/5885/unable-to-solve-word-problems-fluent-in-arithmetic?rq=1#comment10944_5885) for related material.

Comment: The name of these word problems is one-step problems.

Comment: old joke: "If there are 3 apples and you take 2, how many do you have?"

Comment: When I taught Physics it never ceased to amuse me how much adding one unnecessary piece of information would throw the plug-and-chugger into chaos.

Comment: These are one operation problems: A = B * C, where * is any operation. The problems are imprecise. The first is the least problematic, but who knows what happened to other apples while Andy was eating the first two. The second one does not define "far". If Beth drove on a ring road or a bent road or went there and back, and if "how far" means the shortest distance from the start, the "how far" can as well be zero. In the third problem there is no definition how the money should be split.